# problema com CSS com PrimeFaces

Tags: css, primefaces

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou querendo tira as bordas do campo Modalidade, sendo que não conseguir, estou achando que uma pesteira que estou errado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="frm">

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <f:facet name="header">
    Cadastro de Contratos Algaworks
    </f:facet>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Razao Social" for="razao" />
            <p:inputText id="razao" value="#{cadastroContratoBean.razaoS}"
                required="true" />
            <p:outputLabel value="CNPJ" for="cnpj" />
            <p:inputMask id="cnpj" mask="99.999.999/9999-99" maxlength="20"
                value="#{cadastroContratoBean.cnpj}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Cidade do Contrato" for="cidade" />
            <p:autoComplete id="cidade"
                value="#{cadastroContratoBean.cidades_do_Contrato}" required="true"
                completeMethod="#{cadastroContratoBean.sugerirCidades}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Modalidade" for="modalidade" />
            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{cadastroContratoBean.tipo}" id="modalidade" required="true" styleClass="sem-bordas">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="EAD" itemValue="EAD" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Presencial" itemValue="Presencial" />

            </p:selectOneRadio>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar"
            action="#{cadastroContratoBean.Cadastrar}" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.sem-bordas td{
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o seguinte teste.:

1. Add o !important ex.: `.sem-bordas td{
   border: none !important;
   padding: 5px !important;
   }`
   Para identificar se tem alguma classe que esta sobrepondo seu estilo adicionado.
2. Também não sei se o td existe no html gerado pelo f:selectItem.

**Importante:** A melhor forma de identificar esses problemas é inspecionado o elemento pelo próprio browser.

Comment: Só para confirmar que sim, ele gera uma tabela.